# Background data task in watchOS

Tags: watchkit, watchos, urlsession

I'm trying to build a basic proof-of-concept watchOS app and complication that pulls JSON data from an API and displays a gauge based on that.
I've watched Apple's ['Keping your watch app up to date'](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/218/) and found several other questions on the subject but the sample code has been taken down.

The API provides forecasts for the next ~48 hours and can be used to populate the timeline entries for the complication. When the Complication Controller requests the timeline entries I pull the data from the Extension Delegate and therefore it must be kept up to date. However the process of scheduling background data tasks has got me stumped. When I call `backgroundSession.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://......` I expect my `URLSessionDataDelegate` functions to be called but they never are and I never get a the `handle(_ backgroundTasks)` called with `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask`

**Question:**
   When a `WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask` is sent to my `ExtensionDelegate` how should I request/schedule data from the API and then receive it?

**Code**

```
//ExtensionDelegate
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {

...


func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        switch task {
        case let backgroundTask as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask:
            print("background task as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask")
            self.scheduleURLSession()
            backgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            return


        case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
            print("background task as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask")
            let backgroundConfigObject =
                URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: urlSessionTask.sessionIdentifier)
            let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
            print("Rejoining session ", backgroundSession)

            self.savedTask = urlSessionTask
            return
        default:
            // make sure to complete unhandled task types
            task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        }
    }
}





func scheduleURLSession() {
    let backgroundConfigObject = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "nz.co.craigstanton")
    backgroundConfigObject.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true

    let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let dataTask = backgroundSession.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://craigstanton.co.nz/uvi-test?latitude=-36&longitude=174")!)

    print("scheduleURLSession about to 'resume' ")
    dataTask.resume()
}


//Delegate callbacks
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    print("Data task error", error)
}


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {

    print("urlSession Delegate did receive everything ")
}

func urlSession(_: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    print("urlSession Delegate did receive something ")
}
```